# JQUERY Get previous and next value in $.each loop

Tags: jquery, loops

I have a problem in a loop in JQUERY. I retrieve thanks to a "get" query some data (in JSON format).

I would like to insert these data in a dropdown list with "optgroup". But I have problems for doing the optgroup.

I would like to **compare the previous value with the current value in the $.each loop** before inserting the optgroup:

=> IF current_value (v.SG_CODE ) != previous_value(v.SG_CODE) THEN add optgroup

But I don't know how to get it. Could you please help me ?

I have this code:

```
function myFunction (param){

        var select = $("#myselect");
        select.empty();
        select.append(
            new Option('Loading...', '-1')
        );
        var jqXHR = $.getJSON( "myCFC.cfc", {
            "method" : "myMethod",
            "param":    param,
        });

        setTimeout( function(){
        // If status in pending, call the method fail   
            if ( jqXHR && jqXHR.state() === "pending" ){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }
        }, 3000 ); // 3s

        jqXHR.done( function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ){
            // success - Treatment of the request
            //console.log( data, textStatus, jqXHR );
            select.empty();     
            console.log(data.length);
            if(data.length>0){
                select.show();                      
                $.each(data,function(k,v){          
                    //alert(v.ID + " --- " + v.VALUE);                              
                        select.append('<optgroup label="' + v.SG_CODE +'">');       
                        select.append('<option value="' + v.ID + '">' + v.SUBJECT_CODE + '</option>');      
                        select.append('</optgroup>');                                       
                });
            }else{
                select.hide();
            }
        });

        jqXHR.fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
            // AJAX Request failed
            console.log( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ); 
        });

        jqXHR.always( function( jqXHR, textStatus ){
        //console.log( jqXHR, textStatus );
        })
    }
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Seb

Comment: where exactly do you want the comparison?

Comment: I would like to compare  v.SG_CODE [currentrow]  with  v.SG_CODE[currentrow-1] before for adding the optgroup:  select.append('<optgroup label="' + v.SG_CODE +'">');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the previous value with:

```
data[k-1].SG_CODE
```

But first test *k* to be non-zero, as for zero there is no previous element, and referencing `SG_CODE` or other property would trigger an exception. So your `if` could look like this:

```
if (k == 0 || v.SG_CODE != data[k-1].SG_CODE) {
    // ... add
}
```

Comment: This won't work if data is an object. This will work only with array.

Comment: @Miqdad Ali, it seems to be an array since the code has `if(data.length>0){`. A non-Array object could in theory have a numerical `length` property, but then it would not have `length.SG_CODE`, so it would have to be an non-enumerable `length` property. Quite a stretch, if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is, you can do it simply storing last key in temporary variable

```
var lastKey = -1
$.each(data,function(k,v){

   if(data[lastKey]. SG_CODE !== v. SG_CODE ){
       //add to group
   }
   lastKey = k;
}
```